# Is there any capabilities to set Firefox browser zoom level to some specific percent throughout script execution?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, desiredcapabilities

I'm using Firefox browser and i want to set the zoom level 90% while it executing the script.

I have tried to set using `JavascriptExecutor` like -

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.body.style.transform='scale(0.9)'");
```

Its working for specific command lets say in my Listeners file i have place this if its a `get` command. it resize the browser after get URL and then it restored back to default once another command getting executed.

I'm looking for the solution like `DesiredCapabilities` of things so there i can add the zoom level for the browser.

Comment: How about setting the size of the window once you figure out what size suits your requirement?

Comment: You can't set zoom. But you can set `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` to `0.9` to simulate a zoom level, that is in the firefox profile

Comment: @TarunLalwani, can you brief me how do i use this one in my code ?

Comment: Please check the answer I posted

Comment: You could use robot class to simulate the keyboard event - Control & Subtract - to  zoom out of the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FirefoxProfile profile= new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference( "layout.css.devPixelsPerPx", "0.9" );
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

The above will set the firefox profile preference and simulate a zoom level of `90%` for `110%` set it to `1.1`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this one -

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Dimension dMax = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int mHeight = (int) (dMax.height *.9);
        int mWidth = (int)(dMax.width *.9);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(mWidth, mHeight);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
        System.out.println( driver.manage().window().getSize());

    }

}
```

Comment: This sets the window size 90% not the content of a site to be visible in zoom level 90

Answer (score 0):

There is not the capability level option is available in Firefox.
But screen size can be increased or decrease by webdriver:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(value);
```